# JavaScript / jQuery - Change radio button with Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a basic form with a radio button..

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="status" value="on"> On<br>
  <input type="radio" name="status" value="off"> Off<br>
</form>

<br>
<br>

<input id="checkBox" type="checkbox">On / Off
```

I am looking for a way to control the radio button by clicking the checkbox.  Does anybody have an example I can see?

Answer (score 2):

*Two-way*! From radios to checkbox and *vice↔versa*

P.S:     Since the **checkbox is unchecked** by default, you need to set the `checked` attribute to the *off* radio as-well, to reflect such initial state!

```js
var $radios = $('[name="status"]');
var $checkbox = $("#checkBox");

// Handle checkbox click
$checkbox.on("change", function() {
  $radios.filter(":not(:checked)").prop("checked", true);
});

// Handle Radios click
$radios.on("change", function() {
  $checkbox.prop("checked", this.value === "on");
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label><input type="radio" name="status" value="on"> On</label>
  <br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="status" value="off" checked> Off</label>
</form>

<br>
<br>

<label>
  <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox">On / Off
</label>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet in ecmascript 6.

```js
function getElementWithID(id){return document.getElementById(id);}

window.addEventListener('load', ()=>
{
  const checkbox = getElementWithID("checkbox");
  const onButton = getElementWithID("on-button");
  const offButton = getElementWithID("off-button");
  
  function init()
  {
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', ()=> setValues());
    setValues();
  }
  
  function setValues()
  {
    onButton.checked = checkbox.checked;
    offButton.checked = !onButton.checked;
  }
  
  init();
});
```

```css
html
{
  background: #222222;
  color: white;
  font-family: "helvetica neue", helvetica, sans-serif;
}

form
{
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>hokjes</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta name="author" content="Dani van der Werf" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
</head>
 
<body>
 <form action="">
  <input id="on-button" type="radio" name="status" value="on">On<br>
  <input id="off-button" type="radio" name="status" value="off">Off<br>
 </form>

 <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">On / Off
</body>
</html>
```

Please don't use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate the radio buttons. This is an example with ids.

```
$('#checkBox').click(function () {
    if (this.checked == true) {
    $('#on').attr('checked', 'checked');
  } else {
    $("#off").attr('checked', 'checked');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A `<label>` can be associated with a form control by setting a [`for` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Attributes#attr-for) with the value of a form control's `#id`. This makes the `<label>` a *proxy* or *interface* for the linked form control.

Demo 1 is a JavaScript solution. Using the *label link* is to improve the checkbox's appearance, and [**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) was used to set/get the form controls.

Demo 2 is a CSS solution. The `<label>`s are linked directly to the radio buttons. The use of the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) along with the [`:checked` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) made it possible without a checkbox at all.

#### Demo 1 - JavaScript

```js
// Get all of the form controls in form#main
var main = document.forms['main'].elements;

/* Register checkbox to the change event...
|| call onOff function when a change has occured
*/
main.chx0.onchange = onOff;

function onOff(e) {

  /* if #chx0 is checked...
  || get the first form control and click it
  || otherwise click the second form control
  */
  if (this.checked) {
    main[0].click();
  } else {
    main[1].click();
  }
}
```

```css
#chx0 {
  display: none
}

input {
  font: inherit
}

label::before {
  content: '\2610\a0OFF';
}

#chx0:checked+label::before {
  content: '\2611\a0ON';
}
```

```html
<form id='main' action="">

  <input type="radio" name="rad" value="on"> On<br>
  <input type="radio" name="rad" value="off" checked> Off<br>
  <br>
  <input id="chx0" type="checkbox">
  <label for='chx0'></label>

</form>
```

---

#### Demo 2 - CSS Only (2-way)

```css
input {
  font: inherit
}

#off {
  display: none
}

#on::before {
  content: '\2611\a0ON';
}

#on {
  display: inline-block;
}

#off::before {
  content: '\2610\a0OFF';
}

#rad0:checked~#on {
  display: inline-block;
}

#ra0:checked~#off {
  display: none;
}

#rad1:checked~#off {
  display: inline-block;
}

#rad1:checked~#on {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id='main' action="">

  <input id='rad0' type="radio" name="rad" value="on"> On<br>
  <input id='rad1' type="radio" name="rad" value="off" checked> Off<br>
  <br>
  <label id='off' for='rad0'></label>
  <label id='on' for='rad1'></label>

</form>
```